# Enabling console.log in production mode in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, production-environment, console.log

I have over-ridden my console.log to create a log file of everything passed to it. This works great when in dev mode but the log files are empty when in production mode, presumably because console.log doesn't get called?

Anyone know how to enable it so it gets called in production mode?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you rip out your own implementation for now, to see if the console.log actually works properly. Because the console.log should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to print data to the console overview of the Node without using the console function.

```
process.stdout.write("text" + somevar);
```

maybe?

Edit:

The function you are asking consists of printing to the console with timestamp. (Aircoded, might fail, but you'll get the concept)

```
function TSprint(input){
    process.stdout.write(Date.getTime() + " |> " + input + "\n");
}
```

Probably print something like
`January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 |> My input.`

PS: stdout does not create a new line.

Comment: hi, basically i over-rid the console.log to put a timestamp before everything. Then came the requirement to log everything the server does to file so i thought a good place to put that would be in my custom console.log function.... except nothing gets logged when its actually in production :( . i want the log file to be the same as the console output.Thx

Comment: If I understood right, you want to create a function that simulates console.log function but with timestamp. (edit - accidental enter) I will be providing you a function in a minute in my original answer.